# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'imutils.video' error while importing module imutils?

Tags: python, importerror, imutils

I am unable to run this program it shows the following error :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'imutils.video

I tried the solutions online but they are for a different module

I first downloaded the imutils module but it's showing an import error.
The 'deque' name cannot be imported for some reason

this is the code here with the error

[image: 1]

Comment: Pls don’t add images of code. Add code as formatted text to your question.